# Sockets: Simple POST request not working

Tags: java, sockets, http-post

I am trying to make a post request on this page http://www2.gcitrading.com/quotes/converter.asp,
but its not working..I still get the same page after my post request (without the result).

When I use the browser, after I click convert the page turns to http://www2.gcitrading.com/quotes/converter.asp?lang= Im really confused with this one. How can I make this work?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

    String res = "";
        try {
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www2.gcitrading.com", 80));

        in = sock.getInputStream();
        out = sock.getOutputStream();

        out.write(new String("GET /quotes/converter.asp HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(new String("Host: www2.gcitrading.com\r\n\r\n").getBytes());

        while(true) {
            int readSize = in.read(readBuffer);
            if(readSize < 1)
                break;
            res += new String(readBuffer, 0, readSize);
            if(res.contains("</html>"))
                break;
        }

        String cookie = res.substring(res.indexOf("kie:") + 5,res.indexOf("path=/")+6);
        System.out.println("SHow cookie - " + cookie);

        String convert_this = URLEncoder.encode("form_amount=1&form_from_currency=DZD&form_to_currency=USD", "UTF-8");

        out.write(new String("POST /quotes/converter.asp?lang= HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(new String("Host: www2.gcitrading.com\r\n").getBytes());

        out.write(new String("Content-Length: " + convert_this.length() + "\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(new String("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(new String("Cookie: " + cookie +"\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(new String("\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(convert_this.getBytes());

        readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        res = "";

        while(true) {
            int readSize = in.read(readBuffer);
            if(readSize < 1)
                break;
            res += new String(readBuffer, 0, readSize);
            if(res.contains("</html>"))
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(res);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Thanks. Btw, I need to achieve this using c/c++ sockets, but I tested it using java first.

Comment: Try using a program such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at the request you're sending.

Comment: yes..I already thought of that, but the problem is I'm on mac.

Comment: [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/)?

Comment: ok..I'll check this firefox add-on out

Comment: YEAH!! it's solved. There was something lacking in my request I figured it out by using a web debugging proxy tool called Charles. By the way, thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. I used Charles, it's a web debugging tool, and found out that my post request is lacking. I simply added in my post request : `convert_it=true`

Answer (score 1):

I try this it's work

```
String convert_this = URLEncoder.encode("form_amount", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8");
convert_this += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("form_from_currency", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode("DZD", "UTF-8");
convert_this += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("form_to_currency", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode("USD", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
dataOut.writeUTF("[Your String here]");
```

Also, you should be using the higher-level URL, not sockets.

Comment: i need to do this on c/c++ that's why im using sockets\